# Write jest tests for method in functional component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am converting my class component to a functional component.
Here is the code after converting to the functional component

```
function App(props) {
  const { userPreferences, accessLevelProvider, businessProcessesContext } = props;
  const { metaData, buildNumber, globalFilters } = props.appState;
  const [delayReasonEnumName, setDelayReasonEnumStateName] = useState();
  usePortalDomHistoryMonitor();


  useEffect(() => {
    props.getMetaData();
    props.businessProcessesContext.onLoadBusinessProcesses();
    props.getBuildNumber();
    props.getGlobalFilters();
  }, []);

  const setDelayReasonEnumName = (ReasonEnumName) => {
    setDelayReasonEnumStateName(ReasonEnumName);
  };

  const autoLogout = (idle) => {
    // TODO: Start a notification to prompt the user that session will time out soon
    // TODO: Allow user to extend session
    if (!idle) {
      props.onLogout();
    }
  };
```

Here is the Html

```
return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <ErrorNotificationBar />
      <Idle
        timeout={3600000}
        onChange={({ idle }) => autoLogout(idle)}
      />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
```

So I want to write a jest test for autoLogout method. Can anyone help me this out?

Comment: What invokes `autoLogout` in the code?

Comment: If the page is idle for 3 min I am triggering that one. Using react-idle component

Comment: Please update your question to include all relevant code. This means a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component and unit test code example.

Comment: I'll leave as comment as I'm not entirely sure how you'd test this other than mocking the jest timers and "fast forwarding" the 3.6e6 (assumed) milliseconds. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks Basically mock the `onLogout` prop callback, use the fake timers, advance by the idle timeout (plus some delta since JS timers have 4ms minimum delay, and assert that the mocked callback was invoked.